Can I force Watch Series 10/Ultra to show ambient temperature using the water temperature sensor?
Apple Watch 10/Ultra can measure underwater temperature from 0C to 40C. In theory this sensor should also be able to measure ambient temperature.
Is there an app I can install to get data from that temperature sensor? Or maybe some clever way to trick watch into thinking its underwater?

NB: I know this data might not be accurate and I know I can buy an IR thermometer for $25 instead, but I'm curious to access the data and see how accurate the sensor is.

